# How to generate RRULE for recurring events with multiple BYSETPOS values?

Tags: rrule

I'm trying to define a RRULE for an event which occurs on the first and second Monday and Tuesday of each month.  This would equal four event occurrences per month.  I thought this was correct:

```
FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYSETPOS=1,2;BYDAY=MO,TU
```

But it only generates occurrences for the **first** Monday/Tuesday of each month.  If I remove Tuesday, it will generate occurrences for both the first and second Mondays in the month.  Why can't I specify multiple BYSETPOS values (as the [RRULE spec](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rrule.html) seems to allow) along with multiple BYDAY values?

How would such a rule be properly defined, as it's clear this is not the correct way?

Apparently I'm not understanding the BYSETPOS property clearly.
The doc linked above states:

> bysetpos - If given, it must be either an integer, or a sequence of integers,
>   positive or negative. Each given integer will specify an occurrence
>   number, corresponding to the nth occurrence of the rule inside the
>   frequency period. For example, a bysetpos of -1 if combined with a
>   MONTHLY frequency, and a byweekday of (MO, TU, WE, TH, FR), will
>   result in the last work day of every month.

So I thought it was correct to use BYSETPOS to specify the desired occurrences within the frequency period (as a sequence of integers).

Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would such a rule be properly defined

Simply like this: `BYDAY=1MO,1TU,2MO,2TU`

Relevant quote from the [RFC 5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545):

```
  Each BYDAY value can also be preceded by a positive (+n) or
  negative (-n) integer.  If present, this indicates the nth
  occurrence of a specific day within the MONTHLY or YEARLY "RRULE".

  For example, within a MONTHLY rule, +1MO (or simply 1MO)
  represents the first Monday within the month, whereas -1MO
  represents the last Monday of the month.
```

> Why can't I specify multiple BYSETPOS values (as the RRULE spec seems to allow) along with multiple BYDAY values?

You can - in fact you specified 2 with `BYSETPOS=1,2`. You asked for the 1st and 2nd results. But you want to get 4 occurrences per month (first Monday, first Tuesday, second Monday, second Tuesday), so you should specify 4 occurrences if you *really* wanted to use `BYSETPOS` : `BYSETPOS=1,2,3,4`. I do not recommend `BYSETPOS` though, `BYDAY` is much clearer and simpler to understand.